# use url-loader in vue for images in a specific directory

Tags: vue.js, webpack, module, vue-cli-3, urlloader

Vue-cli has already configured url-loader to load base64 url encoded images for images smaller than 4kb. I need to load all images from a specific assets directory, let's say `@/assets/img/pdf`, as base64 to embed them into a pdfmake pdf.

I've already been trying to modify `vue.config.js` as described in [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports) to edit the `images` rule but of course this impacts all images on the site and it's not what I want.

I tried to add a new rule to use url-loader on files from a single directory

```js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module
      .rule('base64img')
      .test(/src\/assets\/img\/pdf\/(.*)\.+(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i)
      .use('url-loader')
      .loader('url-loader')
      .options({
        limit: 102400,
        fallback: { loader: 'file-loader' },
      })
      .end();
  },
};
```

I import different images and add them to my template

```js
import test1 from '@/assets/img/pdf/test1.png';
import test2 from '@/assets/img/pdf/test2.png';
import test3 from '@/assets/img/test3.png';
```

test3 is loaded as expected, but wierd things happen with test1 and test2. test1 (that is bigger than limit parameter) seems to be encoded with an unknown image

```
data:image/png;base64,bW9kdWxlLmV4cG9ydHMgPSBfX3dlYnBhY2tfcHVibGljX3BhdGhfXyArICI2YmUzZjE4YmY5OGM0ZTNjYWI2MzQxYWI5ZjhmNWJmNi5wbmciOw==
```

and test2 (smaller than limit parameter) seems to be loaded with fallback file-loader but with a wrong hash that is not displaying the image.

Totally opposite on what expected, however none of the two images is displayed.

Comment: did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

First, to specify the assets location, you need to 'include' it instead of configuring it in the test regex.

Secondly, you need to add a new rule to the `images` rule for your desired path:

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module
      .rule('images') // -> Default configuration
      .test(/\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp)(\?.*)?$/)
      .use('url-loader')
      .loader('url-loader')
      .options({
        limit: 4096,
        fallback: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: { name: 'img/[name].[hash:8].[ext]' },
        },
      })
      .end()

      .rule('images') // -> Custom rule specification
      .test(/\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/)
      .include.add(/src\/assets\/img\/pdf\/.*/)
      .use('url-loader')
      .loader('url-loader')
      .options({
        limit: 102400,
        fallback: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: { name: 'img/pdf/[name].[hash].[ext]' },
        },
      })
      .end()
  },
}
```

Configuring a name to the files exported in the `dist` folder by adding a `name` to options can be really helpful when debugging.

Also, you can run `vue inspect --rule images` in the console to check out the rule vue-cli is using and confirm the path is correct.